# Adding Xamarin.Forms to Power saver exception

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is there a way to automatically include my app to the device's power saver exception? I am having this problem that when my app is not on the exception the app cannot ping my server. I discovered this when testing my app on my Samsung galaxy J7 Prime. Is it possible to add my app in the exception automatically or disable power saver altogether?

Comment: #AFAIK I do not think you can do that, After Android Marshmallow the [optimization of Doze and Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html). The specific restrictions are listed in [Power Management Restrictions](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details). Do read the links thoroughly ,Also i have seen that the power saver mode behaviour varies from device to device. You might find a work around in the doze and standby link

Comment: So there is no way to disable power saver mode?

Comment: Pretty much no!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add your app to power saver, The only way to achieved it by custom Android system such as MIUI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIUI or Huawei EMUI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei_EMUI. If you want to run your app in Native Android, agree with hakim, you cannot add your app to power save mode or close the power save mode.